# ¿como puedo cifrar o encriptar manualmente o personalmente una parte de mi código JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cifrado

Hice una prueba muy básica, muy sencilla de cambiar las var y funciona.. El problema es que cualquiera que vea mi código fuente o lo descargue, con un simple alert sabrá la dirección o el "codigo" que quiero ocultar. La prueba que hice fue esta:

```js
var la = "h";
var lb = "o";
var lc = "l";
var ld = ".";
var lf = "p";
var lg = "h";
var lh = "p";
//etc.
var palabra1 = la + lb + lc + ld + lf + lg + lh;
var abrir = palabra1;
```

¿en donde puedo buscar un tema que me pueda dar idea de esto? solo he visto paginas que encriptan todo tu código...
¿como puedo cifrar manualmente o personalmente de forma profesional mi Código?

Comment: no es posible, todo lo que este expuesto en el front sera visible para el usuario, puedes usar babel para hacer que tu javascript sea estandar y funcione con navegadores antiguos y eso lo hace menos legible. otra cosa es procesar todo en el backend, alli nadie tiene acceso (si tienes bien hecha la seguridad). pero si esta en el front, sera visible siempre.
si necesitar tener algo seguro en tu front, debes encriptarlo y desencriptarlo en tu backend

Comment: ¡Muchísimas Gracias Jhonnattan por tu respuesta!

Comment: ¿Si alguien "Malicioso" tiene la dirección en donde tengo un php lo puede descargar y ver el código?

Comment: php solo se ejecuta en el servidor, esos archivos deben tener sus ajustes de permisos para que no puedan ser leeidos desde afuera.  si estan mal configurados cualquiera podra verlos.
https://blog.desdelinux.net/permisos-y-derechos-en-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez esta librería te pueda ayudar,

http://www.jsfuck.com/

Al final nada puede cifrar tu código de verdad, por que el navegador lo tiene que interpretar, pero tal vez puedas complicar descifrar un poco mas.

Otra opción que puedes implementar es manejar tus peticiónes con un token,

https://jwt.io/

Un token valido por las horas que tu le indiques y que puedes validar en tus peticiones que sea correcto y vigente para generar una respuesta.
Este lo puedes guardar en el SessionStorage durante el login y enviarlo en tus peticiones